# Python - Get class of type from imported module

Tags: python

I am trying to import a class from a file with a dynamic name. Here is my file importer:

```
def get_channel_module(app, method):
    mod_name = 'channel.%s.%s' % (app, method)
    module = __import__(mod_name, globals(), locals(), [method])
    return module
```

This imports the specific python file, for example, some_file.py, which looks like this:

```
class SomeClassA(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return

class SomeClassB():
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return
```

What I want to do is return only the class which extends BaseClass from the imported file, so in this instance, SomeClassA. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this by inspecting the symbols in your module with `issubclass`:

```
def get_subclass(module, base_class):
    for name in dir(module):
        obj = getattr(module, name)
        try:
            if issubclass(obj, base_class):
                return obj
        except TypeError:  # If 'obj' is not a class
            pass
    return None
```

Answer (score 4):

Once you have your module imported, iterate it's namespace looking for class objects that are subclasses of BaseClass.

```
klasses = [c for c in module.__dict__.values() if isinstance(c, type)]
base_subclasses = [c for c in klasses if issubclass(c, BaseClass]
## or as a single list comprehension
base_subclasses = [c for c in module.__dict__.values() if isinstance(c, type) and issubclass(c, BaseClass)]
```

Comment: Which is basically the same as the answer provided by @Ferdinand Beyer

Comment: `isinstance(c, type)` does not work with old style classes. Should use `inspect.isclass(c)` instead. Or perhaps even `klasses = inspect.getmembers(module, inspect.isclass)`.